# In html file background is not showing behind all content area

Tags: html, css

I am designing a page on www.bookmyshirt.co.cc/hair/city.html
In main div it has two div:
1) block_header
2)main_out

but main_out is not showing grey background to all of its content rather it shows only grey background to some height i want that grey background to all of its content.
and also at bottom that button also merge with above content.
any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: I'm unable to view that link. My Antivirus software blocks it

Comment: link is absolutely fine your antivirus may be block bcoz of co.cc domain

Answer (score 0):

main-content1 is in position absolute.. that's why main-content cant set the proper height.

Remove the position absolute an you'll see the grey background

**EDIT:**

your problem is that you set the heights for different divs but the content of your divs are bigger than the height you gave them (e.g .main-content, .deals) if you have a dynamic content or if you dont know the height of the div, just remove that property in the css.
To solve the problem of the register button, remove the height on `.deals`

Comment: Awesome man you save my lots of time but little help needed for register for hair button and if i remove height of deal div then that box become thin line why?